# Aliasing db4o between C# and F#

Tags: c#, f#, db4o

I have created a db4o database in a C# solution called SyncManage2. That is the assembly name, and also the namespace. There is a class in there called DicEntry.

I want to access that database from another C# solution called SyncText2, which contains two projects, one of which is an F# project with the assembly name of GlossWorks, which does the database work. The F# database code lives in a module called Glossing.

So, how to set up a TypeAlias? I've tried every combo I can think of, but no joy

```
let openDictionary():IEmbeddedObjectContainer =
   let alyas = TypeAlias("SyncManage2.DicEntry,SyncManage2","Glossing.DicEntry,GlossWorks")
```

-- all the way up to --

```
    let alyas = TypeAlias("SyncManage2.DicEntry,SyncManage2", "SyncText2.GlossWorks.Glossing.DicEntry,GlossWorks")
```

but I can't access it.

The ObjectManager showed simply: 'SyncManage2.DicEntry, SyncManage2'

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I managed it the other way -- letting the F# application GlossWorks (with module Glossing and a Type DicEntry) build the db4o database, and accessing it from a different C# app called SyncView2 with a class DicEntry.

```
TypeAlias alyas = new TypeAlias("Glossing+DicEntry, GlossWorks", "SyncView2.DicEntry, SyncView2");
```